# How to disconnect update_last_login?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-authentication

I implemented my own `User` class from scratch in Django. But when I log in I have this error:

> The following fields do not exist in this model or are m2m fields: `last_login`

I *really* don't want the field `last_login`.

I do some reasearch and the problem is here: [`contrib.aut.models.py`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.7.5/django/contrib/auth/models.py#L20-L27)

```
def update_last_login(sender, user, **kwargs):
    """
    A signal receiver which updates the last_login date for
    the user logging in.
    """
    user.last_login = timezone.now()
    user.save(update_fields=['last_login'])
user_logged_in.connect(update_last_login)
```

I found a workaround but it's not an ellegant solution. I added `user_logged_in.disconnect(update_last_login)` in my `models.py` file, where my `User` class is defined.

Is there any better solution for this?

Comment: Do you inherit from Django User model or mixins?

Comment: No I don't. If I inherit from Django `User` also inherit the `last_login` field (and *some* others).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently in Django 1.7...

I think the workaround you defined is the only valid solution (besides from a monkey patch) currently when using the Django auth `login()` method.  I'm just going to assume you are using the standard `login()` method which is raising this exception.

If we take a look at [the source for the login method](https://github.com/django/django/blob/0f7f5bc9e7a94ab91c2b3db29ef7cf000eff593f/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py#L89), we find at the end of the method, a call to execute `user_logged_in.send(sender=user.__class__, request=request, user=user)`.  We can't prevent this signal from executing besides from disconnecting it as you have pointed out.

Alternatively, we could monkey patch the `login()` method to remove that signal call.

```
from django.contrib.auth import login

def monkey_patch_login(request, user):
    """
    Persist a user id and a backend in the request. This way a user doesn't
    have to reauthenticate on every request. Note that data set during
    the anonymous session is retained when the user logs in.
    """
    session_auth_hash = ''
    if user is None:
        user = request.user
    if hasattr(user, 'get_session_auth_hash'):
        session_auth_hash = user.get_session_auth_hash()

    if SESSION_KEY in request.session:
        if _get_user_session_key(request) != user.pk or (
                session_auth_hash and
                request.session.get(HASH_SESSION_KEY) != session_auth_hash):
            # To avoid reusing another user's session, create a new, empty
            # session if the existing session corresponds to a different
            # authenticated user.
            request.session.flush()
    else:
        request.session.cycle_key()
    request.session[SESSION_KEY] = user._meta.pk.value_to_string(user)
    request.session[BACKEND_SESSION_KEY] = user.backend
    request.session[HASH_SESSION_KEY] = session_auth_hash
    if hasattr(request, 'user'):
        request.user = user
    rotate_token(request)

login = monkey_patch_login
```

We would put the monkey patch code at the top of the file that needs to call the `login()` method.

Answer (score 6):

Not sure if this is related to a newer version of django or what, but in my case

```
user_logged_in.disconnect(update_last_login)
```

didn't work. This is what works for me (django 2.1):

```
user_logged_in.disconnect(update_last_login, dispatch_uid='update_last_login')
```

Comment: Confirmed in my case as well. The accepted answer did not work but this does.

Comment: Working in Django 3.0